# Deleting from an array based on a string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have defined an array like so :

```
var myArray = {myNewArray: ['string1' , 'string2' , 'string3']};
```

I want to iterate over the array and delete an element that matches a particular string value. Is there a clean way in jQuery/javascript to achieve this ?

Or do I need to iterate over each element, check its value and if its value matches the string im comparing, get its id and then use that id to delete from the array ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery

Comment: If you don't want to use that method, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Comment: @FireLizzard https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: @FireLizzard - Oh no, [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @Derek That's news to me. I mostly have been using them as a casual documentation resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript arrays have an `indexOf` method that can be used to find an element, then `splice` can be used to remove it.  For example:

```
var myNewArray = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

var toBeRemoved = 'B';
var indexOfItemToRemove = myNewArray.indexOf(toBeRemoved);
if (indexOfItemToRemove >= 0) {
    myNewArray.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);
}
```

After that code executes, `myNewArray` is `['A', 'C']`.

Comment: This is a bit more efficient than my solution, I think.  I'm not sure exactly how `indexOf` works, though, it may simply be a selection search! :D

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a JSFiddle showing your solution](http://jsfiddle.net/h6dMW/)

```
var strings = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
document.write('initial data: ' + strings);
var index = 0;
var badData = 'c';
for(index = 0; index < strings.length; index++)
{
    if(strings[index] == badData)
    {
        strings.splice(index, 1);                 
    }        
}

document.write('<br>final data: '+ strings);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
filteredArray = myArray.myNewArray.filter(function(el){
  return el === "string";
});
```

You can check compatibility at [Kangax's compat tables](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the array using `$.grep`

```
var myArray = {myNewArray: ['string1' , 'string2' , 'string3']};
myArray = { myNewArray: $.grep(myArray.myNewArray,function(val){
    return val !== "string1";
})};
//console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my newARR = oldArr.splice( $.inArray( removeItem , oldArr ) , 'deleteThisString');
```