# How do I find an array within a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I am currently searching:

```
function RemoveQuestion(question)
    {
        $.each(questionCollection, function (index, item)
        {
            var indexToRemove;
            if (item["PprID"] == question["PprID"])
            {
                //This question needs to be removed.
                indexToRemove = index;
                return false;
            }
        });

        questionCollection.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
```

I feel like looping through every array instance, then looking at the array inside of it might be a bit slow.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery inArray() to find the item, then remove it

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

You may even be able to use jQuery grep to find the item and splice it out:

[How to remove specifc value from array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

To check the array you need this:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( item ) === '[object Array]' ) {
  // do some
}
```

To find element within an array you can use jQuery **[`.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/inarray)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `questionCollection` to be a hash of arrays. Or you could build and indexing hash from it first, assuming you only need to do that once to remove multiple questions.

```
function IndexQuestions()
{
    $.each(questionCollection, function (index, item)
    {
        questionIndex[item["PprID"]] = index;
    });
}
function RemoveQuestion(question)
{
    var indexToRemove = questionIndex[question["PprID"]];
    if (indexToRemove != null)
    {
        questionCollection.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

```
function RemoveQuestion(question) 
{ 
    questionCollection = $.grep(questionCollection, function (item) {
        return (item.PprID === question.PprID);
    }, true);
}
```