# Finding element in Javascript object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object array like

```
var objArr = [Object{key="1", value="a"}, Object{key="2", value="b"}, ...]
```

Do we have any Jquery method find the object and delete it. I know using `$.each`

```
$.each(objArr, function(index, obj) {

})
```

But do we have any easy and efficient solution for this?

Comment: it's important to note that every solution to this problem will always be linear efficiency. `each` just loops, `filter` just loops. nothing magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without jQuery, by simply using [the filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of javascript :

```
var filtered = objArr.filter(function(o){return o.key!='badkey';});
```

(note that the MDN page offers tips for the compatibility with very old browsers)

Answer (score 0):

To find the element you could use the .grep() function 
Example:Filter an array of numbers to include numbers that are not bigger than zero.

```
$.grep( [0,1,2], function(n,i){
return n > 0; 
},true);
```

Result:
 [0]

Or if you only need to find the position of that element, you could use the .inArray() function
Example: Find the position of the element that matches with: "1"

```
var arr = [ 4, 2, 3, 1, "hello" ];
var exist = $.inArray(1, arr);
```

Result:

exist = 3

And for delete, theres a post that maybe can resolve your problem 
[How to remove specifc value from array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery)