# How to remove the unchecked item from Array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to put it in array when user checks the check box.. but when user unchecks the check box how do I need to remove from the Array?

```
 $(function () {
   var listval = [];
        $('input[name="checkedRecords"]').bind('click', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                listval.push($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                //How to remove the Unchecked item from array..
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery

Comment: Why not generate the array whenever you need it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an array

```
var mylist = ['a','b','c','d'];
```

To remove the value 'b':

```
if ((index = mylist.indexOf('b')) !== -1)
    mylist.splice(index, 1);
```

Results in:

```
mylist == ['a','c','d'];
```

For your application:

```
 $(function () {
   var listval = [];
        $('input[name="checkedRecords"]').bind('click', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                listval.push($(this).val());
            }
            else {
                if ((index = listval.indexOf($(this).val())) !== -1) {
                    listval.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I updated the answer to spoon-feed you the answer so you don't have to put an iota of thought into it.

Comment: I am getting a page error saying Object does not support this property or method.

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming from this code? Do a `console.log($(this))` at the top of the function and see what is triggering the click

Comment: I am sure error is coming from this line of code if ((index = listval.indexOf($(this).val())) !== -1)

Comment: You could use `$.inArray` instead.