# Remove set of items from an array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I remove specific items from an array with jQuery?

```
var rundhalsArray = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100"];

var Array = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100", "50236765_001", "50236765_100"];
```

I'd like to remove from `Array` all the items in `rundhalsArray`.

Comment: You can refer this : 

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-add-and-remove-array-value-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var rundhalsArray = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100"];
var _Array = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100", "50236765_001", "50236765_100"];

$.each(rundhalsArray, function(k,v){
    $.each(_Array, function(k2,v2){
        if(v===v2) _Array.splice(k2,1);
    });
});

console.log(_Array);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/df5L3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [ "50237451_001", "50237451_100", "50236765_001", "50236765_100" ];
var b = [ "50237451_001", "50237451_100" ];

var minus = function ( a, b ) {
    return a.filter(function ( name ) {
        return b.indexOf( name ) === -1;
    });
};            

var result = minus( a, b );

document.write( result );
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fqDqU/1/) with working example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nPgD7/)

```
Array.filter(function(e){return !~$.inArray(e,rundhalsArray)});
```

`$.inArray()` is to support older browsers, you could use Array.prototype.indexOf method instead.