# compare two arrays and show only the matching items Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var rundhalsArray = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100"];
var Array = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100", "50236765_001", "50236765_100"];
```

I have two arrays and would like to only display the items that match when comparing them so the result of the above would be:

```
var resultArray = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100"];
```

Comment: please show us what you've tried.

Comment: jQuery doesn't provide any methods for that.

Comment: How's this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522169/remove-set-of-items-from-an-array-jquery?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/kL69J/

This is how I would do it:

```
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"];
var foo = [];

$.grep(array2, function(el) {

    if ($.inArray(el, array1) != -1) {
        foo.push(el);
    }

});


alert(" they have the same " + foo);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful snippet. Helped a lot @Pedro Estrada

Answer (score 1):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YGTg4/1/)***

```
var rundhalsArray = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100"];
var arr = ["50237451_001", "50237451_100", "50236765_001", "50236765_100"];

var result = [];
$.map(rundhalsArray, function (val, i) {
    if ($.inArray(val, arr) > -1) {
        result.push(val);
    }
});
console.log(result);
```