# Remove an element from array not splice

Tags: jquery, arrays

`var ar=['apple','mango','ronaldo']` 
What i want is remove mango so it looks like `['apple','ronaldo']`.

i tried this `ar.splice(1,1)` but it gives `['mango']` as output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove specifc value from array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery)

Comment: Works fine - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/TUDsG/). Sounds like you're assigning the return value of `splice()`, rather than just splicing the array

Comment: Oh got the error thanks billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.splice()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) method remove the specific item into the original array and returns the removed item(s).

Try this:

```
var ar = ['apple','mango','ronaldo'];
var ind = ar.indexOf('mango');
if (ind > -1) {
    ar.splice(ind, 1);
}
console.log(ar);
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ9rL/4/)

I recommend to use .splice() method if you want to remove array item using item-index. But you can try this one if want to remove the item by it's value.

```
var ar= ['apple','mango','ronaldo'];
var removeItem = "mango";
ar = jQuery.grep(ar, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
ar //['apple','ronaldo'].
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ9rL/2/)

**Problem when you remove the item by value (i.e "mango") : It's remove all the items of array with the name of "mango" See in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ9rL/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

`ar.splice(1,1)` remove element from array

so the array `ar` is now `['apple','ronaldo'].`

```
var ar=['apple','mango','ronaldo'];
ar.splice(1,1)  // removed 'mango'
ar //['apple','ronaldo'].
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/De4nn/) check console logs

[.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function () {
   var ar=['apple','mango','ronaldo']
   ar.splice(1,1) // remove first
   alert(ar);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4Tj/22/)

Comment: There's no need for any jquery here whatsoever

Comment: @billyonecan question tagged in jquery so i answered lik that'