# Unable remove specifc value from array using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have got an array

And i am trying to remove a specfic element from the array

I tried this way

```
var existingLabels = [1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4];


var loc_name = 1;

 existingLabels = $.grep(existingLabels, function(loc_name) {
  return loc_name != loc_name;
});

alert(existingLabels);
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the first array element, or the array element that has a value of `1`? Obviously they're the same in this example, which is why I need clarification.

Comment: I am trying to remove the lement which has got value 1 .

Comment: So how's this different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery?

Comment: @j08691 The same, however OP's problem is that he picked unfortunate name for current iteration element inside grep callback.

Answer (score 0):

Comparison condition inside grep callback makes no sense because of unfortunate variable name:

```
return loc_name != loc_name; // always false
```

Corrected script:

```
existingLabels = $.grep(existingLabels, function(el) {
    return el != loc_name;
});
```