# Remove a record in a Object Array jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

**EDIT** : Included more details

Hi I have a Object Array in jQuery which looks like this,

[image]

My question is how can I delete a record from that object array by `columnheader` as parameter. I know there is this

```
var result = $.grep(records, function(e){ return e.columnheader == currentheader; });
```

but `grep` i only used to check if there's a matching data based on `currentheader` that i passed in. What if I want to delete?

I want to delete a record on the fly as I am looping in that object array, lets I have. `data` contains all object arrays that is shown in the image.

```
$.each(data, function(key,value) {
   // Let's say I want the code here to delete a record in the current object array that I'm looping into.
});
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove specifc value from array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery)

Comment: you can use jQuery `filter` to remove elements from array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```
arr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return e.columnheader !== currentheader;
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'John Skeet',
  rank: 1
}, {
  name: 'T.J.Crowder',
  rank: 10
}];

console.log(arr);

arr = arr.filter(function(e) {
  return e.rank !== 10
});

console.log(arr);
```

**UPDATE**

> I want the code here to delete a record in the current object array that I'm looping into

Changing a property from object in array.

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'John Skeet',
  rank: 1
}, {
  name: 'T.J.Crowder',
  rank: 10
}];


$.each(arr, function(index, obj) {
  if (obj.rank === 10) {
    arr[index].rank = 9;
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No sir, I don't need to create a new array, I just want to delete a record from an existing object array.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca You can assign the result of filtering to the same array, by doing this you're removing an element from arrary. I've updated answer, check the demo

Comment: I revise my question Sir, it doesn't work for me. You can check my question again for additional details.

Comment: Thanks this works for my purpose and I accept it as answer. However s @Emmanouil Chountasis , I agree it is bad practice to delete a record in a variable you currently looping for it might affect the iterations so I have to change my logic. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript splice method to do it. First find the index of your object in the array then use the method like that :

```
your_array.splice(obj_index,0);
```

**EDIT**

The easy way but not optimized is to use a for loop to get the index, a better solution is to use linq.js to get the object, then your_array.indexOf(your_obj);

**EDIT 2**

You can download linq.js here [Linq.js](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

You can use it like this:

```
function DelteObjFromArray(your_value){
   var objToDelete = Enumerable.From(your_array).Where(function (x) { return x.your_property == your_value; }).FirstOrDefault();

   var objIndex = your_array.indexOf(objToDelete);
   your_array.splice(objIndex,1);
}
```

Comment: *First find the index of your object in the array* - I think that's the question

Comment: No. I want to delete the object in the array based on the columnheader without knowing the index.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry but I do not know a way to delete an object without the index.

Comment: I revise my question Sir, it doesn't work for me. You can check my question again for additional details.

Comment: It is a bad practice to delete in a loop, possible the code will fail because the iterator will show a wrong position. I will update my answer in a while.