# remove all cells that contains specific word in array jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

assume that I have this array:

```
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"];
```

I need to remove all cells that contain word "Banana" so that the output array be like this:

```
var fruits = ["Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103"];
```

how can I do that by using Jquery?

I tried this but it is not works true:

```
var found = $.inArray(fruit_id, myarray) > -1; 
myarray.splice(found, 1);
```

I saw [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery),but in mentioned topic, the answer just removes a cell that contains specific word for example "Banana-101" but my question is how can I remove all cells that have for example "Banana"!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specifc value from array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specifc-value-from-array-using-jquery)

Comment: @AlexMcMillan                      var found = $.inArray(fruit_id, myarray) > -1;
                     myarray.splice(found, 1);

Comment: In your code, `found` will be either `true` or `false`. Neither is a valid argument for the `index` argument of `splice`.

Comment: @AndrewL that question remove specific value for example remove "Banana-101", but I need to remove all cells that have "Banana"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"],
    banana = /banana/i; // regex for banana case insensitive

fruits = fruits.filter(function (a) {
    return !a.match(banana);
});

console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: I just tested and it works... I believe some people downvote as if it was an sport.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, now its a regex.

Comment: for performance purposes, I think it's better to put your regex outside the `filter` because it's "compiled" on each iteration...

Comment: lol, something around 76.58227 faster, thank's for the improvemed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `found` will be either `true` or `false`. Neither is a valid argument for the `index` argument of `splice`.

If it's important to modify the **existing** array, loop backward through it and remove entries that match:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"];
var fruit_id = "Banana";
console.log("Before: " + fruits);
var index;
for (index = fruits.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
  if (fruits[index].indexOf(fruit_id) != -1) {
    fruits.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
console.log("After: " + fruits);
```

You loop backward so that if you remove an entry, you don't have to worry about whether to update the index or not.

If creating a new, replacement array is an option, use `filter`:

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"];
var fruit_id = "Banana";
console.log("Before: " + fruits);
fruits = fruits.filter(function(entry) {
  return entry.indexOf(fruit_id) == -1;
});
console.log("After: " + fruits);
```

In both cases I've assumed a case-sensitive match. For a case-insensitive one, use `toLowerCase` on both `fruit_id` and each entry you're checking.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 with some trikcy js, it's about 1 line of code.

`~` is a bitwise operator that turns `-1` falsy and what ever `>= 0` truthy

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"];

var final = fruits.filter(x => ! ~x.indexOf('Banana'));

document.write(final);
```

Obviously, this snippet works only with ES6 complient webbrowsers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out the elements you don't want.

```
var fruits = [
    "Banana-101",
    "Orange-105",
    "Apple-110",
    "Mango-103", 
    "Banana-102",
    "Banana-104"
];

fruits = $(fruits).filter(function () {
    return this.indexOf("Banana") === -1;
});

console.log(fruits); // ["Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your question is not related to jQuery, but the plain javascript. You can take a look over javascript filter method. Don't look for magic method in some frameworks to do this kind of task, take some time and learn javascript. Best regards, and happy learning.

```
var fruits = ["Banana-101", "Orange-105", "Apple-110", "Mango-103", "Banana-102", "Banana-104"];

var word = "Banana";
fruits = fruits.filter(function(value){
    return value.indexOf(word) == -1;
})
console.log(fruits);
```