# Using Jquery How to remove items from the model collection

Tags: jquery

I have model collection in jquery

```
thiz.tprListSearchesAndViews.searchParameters[0].parameters
```

This has 16 parameters list, as shown in the fist screenshot, I need to remove 2 items in the the parameters collection. Could you please help me, how I can do this. I am not getting any idea how I can approach on this using Jquery.

[image: Image2]

[image: Image1]

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596089/how-to-remove-specific-value-from-array-using-jquery

Comment: It's what you're [probably] looking for. It will show you how to remove elements from a given array using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Myara, for your response, Basically mine is not simple array, its a complex model collection, so can you please suggest me how To remove items from thr

Answer (score 0):

removing I think this is what you're looking for:

```
let resultingArray = jQuery.grep(yourArray, function(obj, idx) {
  //if you want to remove based on some of the element's properties
  //use "obj". E.G.: return (obj['id'] === 3204);

  //Otherwise, use idx for element position on the array.
  return ([1, 7].indexOf(idx) === -1);
});
```

in your code:

```
thiz.tprListSearchesAndViews.searchParameters = jQuery.grep(thiz.tprListSearchesAndViews.searchParameters, function(obj, idx) {
  //Filtering by position (removing items at 1 and 7)
  return ([1, 7].indexOf(idx) === -1);
});
```